# Insert function in node in postgre

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

Hello i am following a tutorial and trying to do a simple insert query but getting 404 error.I am trying to input values using postman.

function

```js
function insertUser(req, res, next){
  req.body.users = parseInt(req.body.users);
  
  db.none('INSERT INTO office.users (role_id, office_id, user_name, full_name) ' +
    'VALUES (${role_id}, ${office_id}, ${user_name}, ${full_name})', req.body.users)
   .then(function(){
        res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Inserted one user'
   });
   })
 .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        next();
})
}
```

The stack trace says problem is near "values".i am not getting it.following i flow with the documentation.Something wrong with the query?

Stack trace

POST /api/users 401 83.997 ms - 43
{ [error: syntax error at or near "$"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 102,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '78',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'src\backend\parser\scan.l',
  line: '1053',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }

I am on my 5th day with Node.Bear with me.

Comment: You do `VALUES(columns) VALUES(variables)` - that's not the SQL syntax for inserts, hence the error.

Comment: @vitaly-t sorry the insert syntax was wrong..was trying to look for different solutions and copy paste error..i edited my question sir..still i am getting syntax error near $..doing this thing since hours.

Comment: backticks in SQL string?'VALUES ( ${role_id}, ${office_id}, ${user_name}, ${full_name})'...'  ' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake declaring variable

This worked

```js
 db.none('INSERT INTO office.users(role_id, office_id, user_name, full_name, password)' +
         'values(${role_id},${office_id},${user_name},${full_name},${password})', req.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error code 42601 is a postgres syntax error.  If you were to print our your sql statement to the page you would see something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO office.users VALUES (role_id,office_id,user_name,full_name)values(${role_id},${office_id},${user_name},${full_name})"
```

There's multiple things wrong with this.  First, your preceding your list of columns with `VALUES`.  Second, you have no space between your list of columns and the (proper) `values` key word.  Your statement should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO office.users (role_id, office_id, user_name, full_name) VALUES (${role_id}, ${office_id}, ${user_name}, ${full_name})"
```

Which means your javascript needs to look more like this:

```
db.none('INSERT INTO office.users (role_id, office_id, user_name, full_name) ' +
        'VALUES (${role_id}, ${office_id}, ${user_name}, ${full_name})', req.body.users);
```

Comment: edited my question sir..still getting the systax error at $